# What's the best way to check for duplicate keys in Querystring/Post/Get requests

Tags: c#, query-string

I'm writing a small API and need to check for duplicate keys in requests. Could someone recommend the best way to check for duplicate keys. I'm aware I could check the key.Value for commas in the string, but then I have another problem of not allowing commas in API requests.

```
    //Does not compile- just for illustration
    private void convertQueryStringToDictionary(HttpContext context)
    {
       queryDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string key in context.Request.QueryString.Keys)
        {
            if (key.Count() > 0)  //Error here- How do I check for multiple values?
            {       
                context.Response.Write(string.Format("Uh-oh"));
            }
            queryDict.Add(key, context.Request.QueryString[key]);
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

QueryString is a `NameValueCollection`, which explains why duplicate key values appear as a comma separated list (from the documentation for the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsc9a449.aspx) method):

> If the specified key already exists in the target NameValueCollection
>   instance, the specified value is added to the existing comma-separated
>   list of values in the form "value1,value2,value3".

So, for example, given this query string:  `q1=v1&q2=v2,v2&q3=v3&q1=v4`, iterating through the keys and checking the values will show:

```
Key: q1  Value:v1,v4 
Key: q2  Value:v2,v2 
Key: q3  Value:v3
```

Since you want to allow for commas in query string values, you can use the [GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba5htte.aspx) method, which will return a string array containing the value(s) for the key in the query string.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest("", "http://www.stackoverflow.com", "q1=v1&q2=v2,v2&q3=v3&q1=v4");

    var queryString = request.QueryString;

    foreach (string k in queryString.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(k);
        int times = queryString.GetValues(k).Length;
        if (times > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key {0} appears {1} times.", k, times);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

outputs the following to the console:

```
q1
Key q1 appears 2 times.
q2
q3
```

Comment: I didn't know that. +1 and deleted my inaccurate answer

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. Would you consider rewriting the MSDN website?

Comment: Awesome answer @jeff-ogata , is there a way I can change this behavior, so instead of this `user_ids[]=1,2,3` I'd like to have this: `user_ids[]=1&user_ids[]=2&user_ids[]=3` ?